# Norwegian Refugee travel document

Tags: uk, london, norway, refugees

I have a Norwegian travel document and would like to travel to London- England for 4 days. Do I require a visa?

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on the purpose of your trip, but assuming a tourist or business visit, the answer is yes, you need a visa, as you can see from the government's [visa checker](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/tourism/no).

Answer (score 5):

You can check if you need a visa using the tool available on gov.uk https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Selecting ‘Stateless or refugee’ and assuming you’re travelling alone for tourism the answer is yes, you need a visa.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm a refugee but I'm traveling to visit a family member for 4 days do I still need a visa? in the tracker you stated that I'm not visiting a family member!

Comment: @Randa Your question didn’t provide that information. If you work through the visa check tool yourself using all the relevant information, it will provide the answer.